# Acceleration of the program due to multiprocessing

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing

There is an example and it should perform the following mathematical operation:

**((A - SORT(B))*(А - SORT(C)).**

I want to understand how it is possible to speed up the program code thanks to multithreading or multiprocessing.

Using multithreading (`import Thread from threading`), most likely, will not give the result, since there is a GIL. Last time I tried to use `Process` from `multiprocessing`, but I didn't get any speed gain at all, that's why I'm asking this question.

In this example, it is planned to calculate `part1` and `part2` in different processes, but I do not know how to implement it correctly. I would like to get an example of how to wrap it all up in a `Process` or somewhere else.

By the way, I think you can create lists in different threads, but for this you need to write a function that would create these lists.

```
import random
from time import time

# e = ((A - SORT(B))*(А - SORT(C))

def difference(array1, array2):
    array3 = []
    for i in range(len(array1)):
        array3.append(array1[i] - array2[i])
    return array3

tic = time()
A = [random.randint(0,1000000) for i in range(1000000)]
B = [random.randint(0,1000000) for i in range(1000000)]
C = [random.randint(0,1000000) for i in range(1000000)]
toc = time()
print("Execution time of creating lists:", toc - tic)
# Execution time of creating lists: 6.700585842132568

tic = time()
part1 = difference(A, sorted(B))
part2 = difference(A, sorted(C))

result = [a * b for a, b in zip(part1, part2)]
toc = time()

print("Execution time of mathematical operations:", toc - tic)
# Execution time of mathematical operations: 2.102379560470581
```

I tried to use `Pool` from `multiprocessing` and my code looks like this:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
...
...
...
pool = Pool(processes=2)
result1 = pool.apply_async(difference, [A, sorted(B)])
part1 = result1.get()

result2 = pool.apply_async(difference, [A, sorted(C)])
part2 = result2.get()
```

But the program became slower...

Comment: Shiw us what you have tried for multi-processing.

Comment: The code could be sped up 10x by using numpy. Is this a solution you'd consider or not?

Comment: @KlausD. added.

Comment: @DavideFiocco Thanks, I knew that. I want to understand how to speed up standard code thanks to multithreading / multiprocessing using Python

Comment: ``apply_async`` launches *one* task, and ``.get`` *waits* for that task to complete. Your code never does more than one thing at once – you merely add overhead for branching and waiting for the branches to merge, but only one branch actually *does* anything.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Thanks. I realized I was wrong. How can I really speed up my code thanks to multiprocessing? What module and function I need to use?

Answer (score 1):

Concurrency only provides a speedup if multiple processes are allowed to run at once, instead of running one after the other: `pool.apply_async` starts one process, but `result.get` *waits* until completion of the process. Launch *multiple* tasks via `pool.apply_async` before waiting on all of them.

```py
with Pool(processes=2) as pool:
    # launch both tasks
    result1 = pool.apply_async(difference, [A, sorted(B)])
    result2 = pool.apply_async(difference, [A, sorted(C)])
    # wait *after* both tasks are running
    part1 = result1.get()
    part2 = result2.get()
```

Be aware that `multiprocessing` has notable overhead for launching and managing the processes, as well as copying input and output between them. An example such as this, with only two processes (maximum speedup factor 2) and large input/output, will achieve only little speedup – a speedup factor 1.15 on my machine.